# AutoHotkey: Exit Script without pressing a key after its done

Tags: exit, autohotkey, quit

```
Run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Total CMA Pack\totalcmd.exe"    
^!F1::    
ExitApp
```

My Script works so far but it doesnt quit after its done.
I just want to start totalcommander and send a hotkey combo and then quit.
ExitApp doesnt work for me in this case...:(

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run TotalCommander and send a command, I would change this to:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2    
Run C:\Program Files (x86)\Total CMA Pack\totalcmd.exe
WinWait, TotalCommander
Send, ^!{F1}
ExitApp
```

Your ^!F1::ExitApp defined the hotkey ^!{F1} as the hotkey to run Exit App.
By changing the hotkey to a Send command, you will send the key combination to your Total Commander.

Comment: You might want to double check what [RunWait](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm) does.

Comment: @Armin, You are right. I used Runwait a long time ago when launching some DOS commands where I had to wait.